# what differ Sylius/Sylius and Sylius/Sylius-Standard?

Tags: sylius

What are [Sylius/Sylius-Standard](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius-Standard) and 
[Sylius/Sylius](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius) projects?

[Installation guide](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/book/installation.html) leads to Sylius/Sylius-Standard and http://demo.sylius.org/ shows Sylius/Sylius-Standard.

So what is Sylius/Sylius?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Sylius Standard` uses all the components as add ins (through composer). This means you'll build your app using the sylius components you want.

`Sylius` adds all the components to the `src` directory so you can modify the components yourself if you want to. It's a prebuilt app with the Sylius components already in there.

That's what i think anyway. I've been using the `Sylius` project for the last 6 weeks and it's been incredible. Was a steep learning curve as i was unfamiliar with symfony.

Comment: This is incorrect, the answer below by @Daniel Šádek is the correct answer. The GitHub repository for `Sylius Standard` is tagged as a template. The `composer.json` for `Sylius Standard` reports `sylius/sylius` as a dependency.

Answer (score 4):

`Sylius/Sylius` - is Sylius CORE

`Sylius/Sylius-Standard` - is what you need for starting new project

`Sylius/SyliusDemo` - is prod example of [Sylius DEMO](https://demo.sylius.com)